# Proving an integral identity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, proof, theorem-proving

Assuming  $f$ is continus on $[0,\pi]$, show that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi }xf(\sin x)dx=\frac{\pi }{2}\int_{0}^{\pi }f(\sin x)dx$$

I tried to demonstrate it using integration by parts, but I did not succeed.

I hope they give me some guidelines to demonstrate the exercise.

Comment: For `f==1` your equation isn't true! Please check your equation.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It's true for $f(x)=1$. Both sides $=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min Thanks, you're right!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/ is a right forum for such type questions.

Comment: Why did you asked this question on Mathematica.SE? Is it related somehow to Wolfram Language programming?

Comment: @Huanca Sullca.  Should it belong to Mathematics.StackExchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

Since we have $f(\sin(x))=f(\sin(\pi-x))$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ then we can rewrite $$\int_{0}^{\pi} x f(\sin(x)) d x=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( x f(\sin(x)) + (\pi - x)f(\sin(x)) \right) d x =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x+\pi -x) f(\sin(x)) d x=\\
=\int_{\;0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi f(\sin(x)) d x=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\sin(x)) d x$$
**Q.E.D.**

Assumptions can be weakened to generalize this theorem by substituting $\sin(x)$ by any continuous function satisfying $g(x)=g(\pi-x)$ on $[0,\pi]$, it is sufficient for $f$ to be measurable.
For a graphical representation of the key identity we add a plot:

```
Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
      Epilog -> { Dashed, Line[{{1/3, 0}, {1/3, Sin[1/3]}, {Pi - 1/3, Sin[1/3]},
                                {Pi - 1/3, 0}}], 
                  Thick, Dashed, Line[{{Pi/2, 0}, {Pi/2, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

where we have placed two dashed vertical lines at $x=\frac{1}{3}$ and $x=\pi-\frac{1}{3}$ symmetrically around $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice solution. I think for every function `g[Pi/2+x]==g[Pi/2-x]` the generalization `Integrate[x f[g[x]],{x,0,Pi}]==Pi/2 Integrate[ f[g[x]],{x,0,Pi}]` holds!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes indeed, this is worth to mention.